# Wordpress need username to external script

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to send the wordpress username to a external file when the click on a button on my website.
I have test it with Post but then you can edit your username.

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? I don't really understand what you are asking. What do you mean by send the username to an external file? Are you trying to write the username to a file as a string? What do you mean you tested it with post, but then you can edit the username?

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the user modifying the request, then the request must originate from your server rather than from the user's browser.

To do this, your button should call a script on your server. That script should then retrieve the username from user's current Wordpress session then send that directly to the other server using `libcurl` or a similar library.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't just want to get the log in info to you? I think this might be an attempt scam people logging into your site. You aren't providing any coding info or nothing. Obviously something is wrong here.